# Mutation Testing a boolean variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mutation-testing

Suppose you have a function func:

```
def func(a, b = True):
   if b:
     return 1
   else
     return 0
```

How do you fix the mutant when the code changes to:

```
def func(a, b = False):
   if b:
     return 1
   else
     return 0
```

Do you just write a test case for this?

Comment: Do you not have an existing test where the default value is used? If not, why include the default at all?

Comment: Fix what? The function still returns `1` when `b` is truthy and `0` when `b` is falsey. All you changed is the default value of `b`

Comment: @DeepSpace the behaviour of `func(one_arg)` is different, though.